# CCParticleSystem moving particles with emitter rather than freely

Tags: swift, cocos2d-iphone, spritebuilder

I'm having a spot of trouble trying to get this to work

I basically have a CCParticleSystem (created in Sprite Builder) that I want to follow a sprite but I want the emitter node to leave a trail of sorts... kind of like an airplane leaves a trail of exhaust fumes behind it

As far as I can make out there are no setting in Sprite Builder that I can change to allow this so I went looking for a solution in code

I found this in the documentation:

```
self.myParticleNode.particlePositionType = CCParticleSystemPositionType.Free
```

Which declares that the particles will be positioned relative to the Physics World and not be affected by the position of the emitter, but it appears to not do a thing

Any help or suggestions on this would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I found that CCParticleSystems particle positioning doesn't actually function when the Emitter Node is scaled in any way... this has posed a problem for me because I wanted a zoomed out camera effect.

Never mind.

Looks like this just won't work for now